# Printing text from 2-D list python

Tags: python, pyqt

I am making a GUI using pyqt4. In this application i am storing my result from database in a 2-d list and now i want to print this list in my GUI, but when i do so, every result is being printed on a new line, so how do i print 1 row in a line?

```
for row in to_d_col:
      clm = ''
      for col in row:
          q=q+1
          item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem("%i)  %s"% (q,col))
```

I have tried to store the result in a string and then print it, it works fine by that way but the spaces between the words create a problem.

```
for row in to_d_col:
      clm = ''
      for col in row:
          clm = clm +str(col)+"\t"
      q=q+1
      item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem("%i)  %s"% (q,clm))
      self.listWidget_2.addItem(item)
          self.listWidget_2.addItem(item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use a QtGui.QTableWidget instead of a listwidget, and fill it like so:

```
widget = QtGui.QTableWidget(parent) # or get the widget some other way
for i, row in enumerate(to_d_col):
  for j, value in enumerate(row):
    ci = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(value)
    widget.setItem(i, j, ci)
```